# Intercept traffic from android app

Tags: android, ssl, fiddler, genymotion

I need to intercept requests from the mobile application to take advantage of its internal api. In the application there is a chat, I need to receive the information that the server periodically sends to the application. For this, I installed Genymotion with the Xposed + module to bypass SSLPinning and Fiddler as a proxy (tried also Charles). After that I see some of the traffic from the application (long-polling requests), but the events I need are not displayed, although the application still receives them and displays them.

Can I somehow intercept absolutely all traffic from the application and what should I do to do this? Thank you in advance)

Comment: If the app uses https (and if they aren't, shame on them) it isn't going to be possible anyway-  you'll only get the encrypted data.

Comment: I installed the Fiddler certificate and use SSLUnpinning for Xposed, which allows me to decrypt the traffic. The problem is that the data I need is simply missing from intercepted requests

Answer (score 0):

1. On Fiddler side you have to enable in the settings ***Allow remote computers to connect***.
2. You also need the IP address of your computer in your home network, e.g. 192.168.0.13

Now start the virtual device and configure the proxy (taken from [Genymotion FAQ](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#proxy-configuration)):

> How do I configure proxy settings in my virtual device? In your
>   virtual device:
>
> 1. Click Menu > System settings.
> 2. In Wireless & Networks, select Wi-Fi.
> 3. Click WiredSSID and hold it down for two seconds.
> 4. Click Modify Network.
> 5. Check Show advanced options.
> 6. In Proxy settings, select Manual.
> 7. Enter the proxy settings (***the noted IP address of step 2 of your PC and port 8888***)
> 8. Click Save.